# changing all <td> color onclick for a particular table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

iam using below  code to toggle td color

```
    <html>
    <head>
       <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script>
          $(function(){
             $("td").click(function(){
             $(this).addClass("on").parent().siblings("tr").find("td").removeClass("on");
             });
          });
       </script>
       <style>
          article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
          menu, nav, section { display: block; }
          .on { background-color:red; color:#ffffff; }
       </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <table class="mytable" border=1>
       <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td>Hello World</td>
          <td>Hello World1</td>
          <td>Hello World2</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Hello World</td>
          <td>Hello World1</td>
          <td>Hello World2</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Hello World</td>
          <td>Hello World1</td>
          <td>Hello World2</td>
       </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

above code works fine by toggling td color, please check the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/hEvcZ/1/)

but now i need to do three things,

1. above code is working for all the tds ,i need it to work only for last column of table class "mytable",
2. i need to add a button which when clicked should change all td's color to "white" of table class "mytable"
3. compleate row should be red color when we select partcular cell.
   please help me to fix this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***HTML***

```
  <table class="mytable" border=1>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Hello World</td>
        <td>Hello World1</td>
        <td>Hello World2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hello World</td>
        <td>Hello World1</td>
        <td>Hello World2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hello World</td>
        <td>Hello World1</td>
        <td>Hello World2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

<button id="change-color">Change Color</button>
```

​
***jQuery***

```
$(function() {
    $(".mytable tr td:last-child").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("on").parent().siblings("tr").find("td.on").removeClass("on");
    })

    $('#change-color').click(function() {
        $('.mytable td.on').removeClass('on');
    });
});​
```

*[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hEvcZ/16/)*

#### According to comment

```
$(function() {
    $(".mytable tr td:last-child").click(function() {
        $('td.on').removeClass('on');
        $(this).parent().find('td').addClass("on");
    })

    $('#change-color').click(function() {
        $('.mytable td.on').removeClass('on');
    });
});​
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hEvcZ/20/)***

Comment: thanks for updating this answer ,, this is what i need..well now particular cell goes to red when selected , is there a way i can change color for the compleate row when particular cell is selected?? please help me with this....

Comment: hello thecodeparadox ,its not working.. as i have mentioned ... user should be able to select only last column cells(if they click on any other cells color should not change) but when particular cell is selected ,compleate row should go red not just one cell(as happening now)

Answer (score 3):

Just change your jQuery selector to `td:last-child`

```
      $(function(){
          $("td:last-child").click(function(){ //this is the changed part
    $(this).addClass("on").parent().siblings("tr").find("td").removeClass("on");
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/hEvcZ/2/

---

For your second question, you need the HTML and jQuery:

HTML:

```
<button id="tableButton">White</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$("button#tableButton").click( function() {
    $("table.mytable *").css({"background":"#fff", "color":"#000"});
});
```

This is one way to do it, you can of course select just the td with the last child selector again, but this code is a good place to start :)

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/hEvcZ/3/

Comment: never.. i dont do downvote for anyone...well check my updated question 'Abody', i need to fix third point now

Comment: _Someone_ did. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

***HTML***
//add the follwing code into html

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="button">
```

***JS CODE***

```
$(function(){
    $('td:last-child').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass("on").parent().siblings("tr").find("td").removeClass("on");
});
});

$('#button').on('click', function(){
   $('.mytable').find('td').css({'background':'#FFF', 'color':'#000'})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For your second question

```
$("#Button_for_color").click( function() {
     $("table .mytable").css({"background":"black", "color":"white"});
});
```

and for the first i didnt sure but it works like

```
$(function(){
      $("td:last-child").click(function(){
       //You can play here
 });
```

hope the second will also works

Comment: please check my updated question dear... i have added 3rd point also.. is there a way to fix?

Answer (score 0):

For your third question:

```
 $(function(){
   $("td").click(function(){
   $("td").removeClass("on");
$(this).addClass("on").parent().siblings("tr").find("td").removeClass("on");
  });
});
```

Comment: I updated my answer for the third query of you...please checkit.accept it if it is useful and works for you

Comment: no its not working... as i have specified ,user should be able to select only last column cells but when particular cell is selected ,compleate row should go red not just one cell(as happening now)...

Comment: just check it once because it works for me in the your "jsfiddle" gives the sol.for the third one

Comment: no..in you code it is selecting only last column cell ,when selected it is highlighting only the cell which is selcted....but as i have mentioned it should highlight full row, but only last column cell should be clickable.. no other cells in a table should be clickable apart from last column cells

Answer (score 0):

Now check this

```
 $(function(){
      $("tr:last-child td").click(function(){
          $("tr:last-child td").addClass("on");
  });
});
```